# GCP table widget showing more than one value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I am trying to create in my dashboard widget with type table, where I can show more than one value for specific operation. I am going through MQL documentation but I failed to find anything useful

Right now I tried to use join or union but the best I got is this

```
    { fetch k8s_container
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/my_metric/count'
| filter (metric.error == 'error')
| group_by 1d 
| every 1m 
| group_by [metric.operation, metric.error];
fetch k8s_container
| metric 'custom.googleapis.com/my_metric/count'
| group_by 1d
| every 1m
| group_by [metric.operation, metric.error], [row_count: row_count()]
} | outer_join 0, 0
```

[image: output table]

In other tries, values has been added to each other or multiplied.

My goal is to show data similar to this table below
[image]

Is it possible to add few values on one table? I would be grateful for any tip or any link to valuable resource/example/documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom table representation using time series widgets and add multiple time series for specific operations in your custom dashboard.

For adding charts and tables to a custom dashboard, see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts).

Comment: but for specific type of widget 'table', I got that error 'multiple queries  are disabled'. When I go to 'json editor' and try to add second 'timeSeriesQuery', it results only with override the first one, not by showing results of two